# ODE system - finding the general solution given 2 solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following ode system

$\begin{cases}tx_1'=2x_2+2x_3+t^3e^t\\tx_2'=-x_1+3x_2+x_3+t^4\\tx_3'=-x_1+x_2+3x_3+t^3e^t\end{cases}$

and $2$ solutions of the system $$u_{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}(a+b)t^2\\at^2\\bt^2\end{pmatrix},\quad u_{(2)}=\begin{pmatrix}2\ln t+1\\ \ln t+1\\\ln t+1\end{pmatrix}$$

> **What is the system's general solution ?**

**Attempt**

I think it is quite clear that some sort of parameters variation is required due to given solutions. The only problem is that I am not sure how to approach this solution.

I tried to develop some sort of a matrix  $$\psi(t)=\begin{pmatrix}(a+b)t^2&2\ln t+1\\at^2&\ln t+1\\bt^2&\ln t+1\end{pmatrix}$$ such that for some $v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix}$ fulfills $\psi(t)v'(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t^2e^t\\t^3\\t^2e^t\end{pmatrix}$;

the same method we solve linear ode systems, but clearly this matrix multipication is undefined.

How should I approach this? Thank you very much!

Comment: These are not solutions of the system, the first is part of the homogeneous solution, the second vector seems not to have any relation to the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system matrix $$A=\pmatrix{0&2&2\\-1&3&1\\-1&1&3}$$ has the characteristic polynomial
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)
%=\det\pmatrix{-λ&2&2\\-1&3-λ&1\\-1&1&3-λ}
=-λ(3-λ)^2-4+λ+4(3-λ)
\\
=-λ^3+6λ^2-12λ+8=(-λ+2)^3
$$
so that substituting $u_k=x_k/t^2$, $u_k'=(tx_k'-2x_k)/t^3$, results in the system
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
tu_1'&=-2u_1+2u_2+2u_3+te^t\\
tu_2'&=-u_1+u_2+u_3+t^2\\
tu_3'&=-u_1+u_2+u_3+te^t
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
As one can see, the homogeneous part is always a multiple of $v=-u_1+u_2+u_3$ with
$$
tv'=t^2\implies v=\frac12t^2+c
$$
and consequently
\begin{align}
tu_1'&=2v+te^t&\implies u_1 &= \frac12t^2+2c\ln t+e^t+d_1\\
tu_2'&=v+t^2&\implies u_2&=\frac34t^2+c\ln t+d_2\\
tu_3'&=v+te^t&\implies u_3&=\frac14t^2+c\ln t+e^t+d_3
\end{align}
with $c=-d_1+d_2+d_3$. With setting $d_2=a+c$, $d_3=b+c$, $d_1=d_2+d_3-c=a+b+c$ one gets expressions close to those you cited, but with extra terms.

Comment: Nice solution! But is it not $x_k = t^2 u_k$?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, you are right.

Comment: It seems like the substitution you used follows from the characteristic polynomial. Could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: It is a shift in the spectrum so that the eigenvalues of the resulting matrix all become zero. $tx'-2x=(A-2I)x+b(t)$ and the integrating factor for the left side is $t^{-3}$ to get $(t^{-2}x(t))'$.

Answer (score 2):

***Another approach ***

$$\cases{tx_1'=2x_2+2x_3+t^3e^t\\tx_2'=-x_1+3x_2+x_3+t^4\\tx_3'=-x_1+x_2+3x_3+t^3e^t}$$
We can observe that $r_2-r_3$ gives :

$$t(x'_2-x'_3)=2(x_2-x_3)+t^4-t^3e^t$$
Thats easy to integrate  (substitute $z=x_2-x_3)$
$$ \implies tz'=2z+t^4-t^3e^t$$ 
$$ \implies t^2z'-2tz=t^5-t^4e^t \implies (\frac z {t^2})'=t-e^t $$
$$ \boxed{\implies x_2=x_3+\frac {t^4}2-e^tt^2+Kt^2}$$
You have $x_2$ as a function of $x_3$ and t

We also have $r_1-2r_3$ which gives another easy integrable equation
$$t(x'_1-2x'_3)=2(x_1-2x_3)-t^3e^t$$
$$\implies tv'=2v-t^3e^t$$
Solve that equation with the same method as for the first one
$$ \boxed{\implies x_1=2x_3-e^tt^2+Ct^2}$$
You get $x_1$ in function of $x_3$ and t

Then take any equation and substitute these values ..and integrate
$$tx_3'=-x_1+x_2+3x_3+t^3e^t$$
$$tx_3'-2x_3=t^3e^t+\frac{t^4}2+Kt^2-Ct^2$$
$$(\frac {x_3}{t^2})'=e^t+\frac t 2+\frac 1t(K-C)$$
$$\boxed{\implies x_3=t^2e^t+\frac {t^4}4+(K-C)t^2\ln|t|+At^2 }$$

Comment: I like this approach, but what are $z,v$ role in the general solution ? are they combined in a matrix in some way ?

Comment: @YarivLevy the first integral gives $x_2$ in funstion of t and $x_3$ same for the second equation...once you have these relations you take any equation of the system and substitute the value of the unknown functions

Comment: @YarivLevy I added some lines I hope it's more clear now

Comment: It is, thank you !

Comment: yw @YarivLevy ......

Answer (score 0):

A quite general solution to these kinds questions is tried here,

The system can be written as
$$
x'(t) = A(t)x(t)+b(t).
$$, with $A(t)$ commuting for all $t$. This has a general solution written as

$$
x(t) = \exp(A(t))\left (x(0) + \int_0^t\exp(-A\tau)b(\tau)\,d\tau \right )
$$

We can solve for $x(0)$ and get
$$
x(0) = \exp(-A(t))x(t) - \int_0^t\exp(-A\tau)b(\tau)\,d\tau 
$$

Let $c(t) = \int_0^t\exp(-A\tau)b(\tau)\,d\tau$, hence
$$
x(0) = \exp(-A(t)) x(t) - c(t)
$$
If you have two solutions $u_1,u_2$, then you get two solutions $x_1(0),x_2(0)$. Assume $x_1(0),x_2(0)$ linearly independent, then you can take $x_3(0) = x_1(0)\times x_2(0)$ and write the general solution as
$$
a_1 x_1(0)+a_2 x_2(0) + a_3 x_3(0) = \exp(-A(t)) x_{a}(t) - c(t)
$$
L.H.S is the same as
$$
a_1 (\exp(-A(t))x_1(t)-c(t)) + a_2 (\exp(-A(t))x_2(t)-c(t)) +a_3(\exp(-A(t))x_1(t)-c(t))\times (\exp(-A(t))x_2(t)-c(t))=L_a(t)
$$
And we get,

$$
x_a(t) = \exp(A(t))(L_a(t) + c(t))
$$ And you can express all solutions with the solutions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$

Comment: This is semi-wrong. Here you get $x'=\frac1tAx+b(t)$ so that the values of $A(t)$ actually commute which is necessary for $\exp(\int A(s)ds)$ to have anything to do with the solution. Then $\int_1^t A(s)ds=A\ln(t)$, so that now you have to compute a matrix exponential $e^{A\ln(t)}\overset?=t^A$, which is done, surprise, using the eigen-decomposition of $A$.

Comment: Thanks LutzL, I agree with you that the comuting must be ensured, I forgot about that. I'll add it

Comment: The exponent is an anti-derivative of $A(t)$. Then you have to consider that $\exp(\int A(t)\,dt)$ is a matrix, so you must be careful in the order of factors.

Comment: @LutzL Yeah, got the order backwards. I think I fixed it now